# How do I change the shape of only part of object to replicate another object's shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I made these two objects but I want to warp one of the objects to have the exact same corner as the other one.

[image]

Comment: While I can appreciate the desiree to post something quickly, and the video *does* help a great deal in understanding the issue... links can and do rot and it's always best to try and describe the problem, at least to a minimal degree within the question itself. That way, future visitors may also benefit from your question. Questions should be *self-contained*. I've converted your video to an animated gif for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the corner anchor to a smooth anchor, then adjust the Bézier handles.

[image]

Comment: I got [this](https://i.gyazo.com/a12e08ef2758d32de4fe0ca8d568d5e1.mp4)

Comment: @5Flux - you aren't adjusting the handles - you are just clicking and dragging on the path. What I suggest you do is take some time to learn how Bézier curves, handles and anchor points work. There are many tutorials for this online. Look them up on youtube.

Answer (score 1):

You also try to be smart along with Illustrator CC!

[image]